# Change SwitchPreference position in a PreferenceScreen layout

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-auto

I need to implement a SettingsFragment for an Android Auto App; From my research, I need to use a PreferenceScreen layout;
Is there a way to change the switch button position from right (implicit) to left?
[I need to implement the following screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNDtk.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found a solution:
You can add a custom layout to the desired object from the preference screen and define that custom layout to match your needs

app:layout="@layout/myCustomLayout"